# Problem using variables and relative paths in Visual studio 2019 (publish profile)

Tags: .net-core, deployment, visual-studio-2019, publish, asp.net-core-1.1

I have imported an old Visual studio 2015 application to Visual studio 2019. I converted everything so it works, execpt one thing. I can't get relative path or environment variables to work in publish profile.
In *DesktopBuildPackageLocation* i have ..\..\..\Deploy\project.zip and it won't work.
For some unknown reason the only variable that I gotten to works is *MSBuildThisFileDirectory*. So I have tried to replace it with $(*MSBuildThisFileDirectory*)..\..\..\..\..\Deploy\project.zip
But that still doesnt work, the error I gets is ...

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Web deployment task failed. (The path '<pathline>\Properties\PublishProfiles\..\..\..\..\..\Deploy\OAS.Parameters.xml' is not valid.)   OAS     0
```

and the diagnostic log gives

```
2021-01-11 21:01:59
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
---> (Inner Exception #0) Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---

Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.

===================
```

If the use a hardcoded path(*shrugg*) it works but it creates a mess with the deployscript and creates an indirect requirement that that path is carved in stone and cannot be changed.
I have tried with variables *BaseOutputPath* and *BaseIntermediateOutputPath* and they seems to be empty.
Any solutions, suggestions and/or ideas?

Comment: What about using a variable in appsettings.json?Add the project path to it.When use the path,you can combine the value of the variable and relative path.

Comment: That works but the error still stands